# Numpy: How to perform the outer product of four vectors and then summing them?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensor

`A = [a1, a2]`, `B = [b1, b2]`, `C = [c1, c2]`, `D = [d1, d2]`.

The outer product of `A, B, C, D` is just:

```
[
    [
        [[a1*b1*c1*d1, a1*b1*c1*d2], [a1*b1*c1*d1, a1*b1*c2*d2]], 
        [[a1*b2*c2*d1, a1*b2*c1*d2], [a1*b2*c2*d1, a1*b2*c2*d2]]
    ],
    [
        [[a2*b1*c1*d1, a2*b1*c1*d2], [a2*b1*c2*d1, a2*b1*c2*d2]], 
        [[a2*b2*c1*d1, a2*b2*c1*d2], [a2*b2*c2*d1, a2*b2*c2*d2]]
    ]
]
```

In numpy, the outer product is thus an array of shape `(2, 2, 2, 2)`. I know how to do this. The problem is, I have 100 this kind of A, B, C, D. They are taken from A_k, B_k, C_k, D_k by fixing k. So they are actually array of shape (2, 100) or (100, 2). Actually may be (20, 100) or (100, 20). I use 2 to simplify the writing. What I want to do is: do this kind of outer product for 100 times and then sum them up. That is: to sum 100 arrays of shape (2, 2, 2, 2). How can I do this efficiently with numpy? If better, is there any GPU acceleration way of doing this?

If A, B, C, D are just 1d array, I know how to do this. The following one-line code works fine:

```
a[:, None, None, None] * b[None, :, None, None] * c[None, None, :, None] * d[None, None, None, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) plus [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) with careful selection of axes should give you what you need.

Comment: Just `einsum` should work with something like `np.einsum('ij,ik,ir,il->jkrl', A, B, C, D)`.

Comment: Agree - and a single call to einsum is probably more efficient than multiple einsum calls + a sum call, as the entire operation is handled once in compiled C code without ever coming back up to python. On the other hand, multiple calls is probably simpler to write if its your first time using einsum. I would write it the easy way first then refactor.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really work. Again only a one-line code is needed:

Comment: Although einsum can do what I want and is much faster than using many for loops, it is still not fast enough. I need to to this kind of outer product summation for several hundred times. Each einsum takes about 3 minutes to compute. Doing 400 such einsum will take 1200 minutes. Is there any faster way to do this?